# how to access dynamically created array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to access the dynamically created array by dereferencing pointer but its showing error.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    int *arr = new int[10];
    arr[0]=10;
    int *num = new int(10);
    cout << *num << " "<<num[10]<<endl;
    cout << arr[0];
}
```

As I know if you want to assign some value to pointer object we have to dereference it then apply like `*num =10` but in terms of array i am not able to do something like`*(arr[0])=10`

it showing error like `operand of '*' must be a pointer but has type "int"`

can anyone explain this to me please?

Comment: Please don't change questions into something else, just create a new question instead.

Comment: G. Sliepen i am not able to asky new qustions so i am editing existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

`int *arr = new int[10];` give you 10*4(int) memory in heap. it doesn't work the same as stack memory it's just plain 10 memory in heap but you can use it as an array. indirectly you are accessing memory and assigning it the value .

Comment: i am not getting what are you trying to say